# How to overwrite form submit button id?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using the `attr` option to set the custom ID for my deletion form button:

```
{{ form_widget(form.delete, { 'label': 'myCustomLabel', 'attr': {'id': 'myCustomId'} }) }}
```

But it works with anything (**'class'** for example) except the **'id'** attribute. The id is still **'form_delete'** and I can't change it even with form builder:

```
$this->createFormBuilder(null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('task_delete', array(
            'prefix' => self::getTaskMapper()::getPrefix($task),
            'id' => $task->getId()
        )))->add('delete', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'delete',
            'attr' => ['id' => 'MyCustomId']
        ])
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm();
```

Why is that the case? How do I overwrite it?

Form id overwriting works well.

Comment: as a note: ids can't be numbers

Comment: I tried words, it doesn't want to be changed

Comment: I'm no twig expert so I can't actually help - but ids can't be numbers full stop, that's just html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you shouldn't be using `attr`. Just set the id on the main `form_widget` options:

```
form_widget(form.delete, { 'label': 'myCustomLabel','id': 'myCustomId' }) }}
```